# How can I build projects from Stackoverflow as Windows program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

I would really like to use this program: https://github.com/iscooool/KeyMouse

In the installation manual it says:
*1. run git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/iscooool/KeyMouse.git.
2. Install Visual Studio and Import this project.
3. Ensure to build this project in x64.*

For visual studio importing, do they mean to simply open the folder downloaded from KeyMouse? Or is there a separate "import project" feature which I did not find in VS Code?
How can I then build the project?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Visual Studio is not the same thing as Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're installing Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ -- Community Edition is likely fine.

Once you have Visual Studio installed, just file, open, KeyMouse.sln - a "solution" is equivalent to a project in Visual Studio...

Comment: Thank you! I did everything you proposed but am unsure what I need to do after having opened KeyMouse.sln.In menu at the top, there are only these options available: "Export template..",  "Manage NuGet packages...." What do I need to run it after opening it in Visual Studio?